# Add new handler to telegrambot on runtime

Tags: go, telegram-bot

I'm using https://github.com/tucnak/telebot to creating a bot in golang. I want to add a handler after the bot has been started but it's not working. in other words, I want to add a handler in runtime.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    tb "gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2"
)

func main() {
    b, err := tb.NewBot(tb.Settings{
        // You can also set custom API URL.
        // If field is empty it equals to "https://api.telegram.org".
        URL: "http://195.129.111.17:8012",

        Token:  "TOKEN_HERE",
        Poller: &tb.LongPoller{Timeout: 10 * time.Second},
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    b.Handle("/delete", func(m *tb.Message) {
        user = m.Sender.ID
        prepareUserButtons(user,b)
        b.Send(m.Sender, "test")
    })

    b.Start()
}

func prepareUserButtons(user int, b *tb.Bot){
        key := "/delete" + strconv.Itoa(user)
        b.Handle(key, func(m *tb.Message) {
            b.Send(m.Sender, "this is sample")
        })
}
```

for make it simple, I wrote a simple sample above. so it's not my code but a sample of what I mean. creating new handler after bot has started ( runtime).

Comment: I dont get, why you need to add handler at runtime? You want handle payload in `/delete` e.g. `/delete?foo=bar` or `/delete1`, `/delete2`, `/deleteN` ?

Comment: @Зелёный, thanks for your attention.do you have any sample to get the payload of the  handler?
in my sample each user has  N items, so I want when for example `delete is calling, I pass the id of the item and user_id to the handler.

Comment: There is `Payload` in the message, https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2#Message.

Comment: @Зелёный can you provide it as a answer with sample? because what I see is that data on bot message.

Comment: I need to mention that you must declare `user` as a new variable by `:=`. Then, it's gonna be `user := m.Sender.ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can create a new handler after the bot has been(main func) started but you have to call the handler before `bot.start()`. You can create a new function called `handleDelete` and there you can handle `/delete` and then call the function right before `bot.start()`. Hope that makes sense.